# Is there a difference between an svn copy and an svn branch?

Tags: svn

I asked one of my developers to give each dev a different copy of the trunk to work on in /branches (under their own name).

That developer is not experienced in subversion (and neither am I), so I'm trying to determine if he did the right thing by copying the trunk into each branch folder and committing it, or if he should have done something else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your friend was correct - to create a branch in Subversion you use the `svn copy` command.

[(Source)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04s02.html#svn-ch-4-sect-2.1)

Answer (score 8):

Subversion doesn't have subprojects, branches or tags, only directories and files (and properties). Whether you treat a certain copy as a subproject, a branch, a tag, a backup, just a plain ol' copy or something else entirely is purely a social convention between you and your teammates.

Answer (score 6):

If he did a copy-paste on his local computer and then committed it as a new addition, then he did it incorrectly and svn will see each "copy" as a separate set of code without any link between them. NEVER DO THIS.

If he did an svn copy (either as a command or using an svn tool), then he did it correctly and svn will link the one as originating from the other (e.g. you will be able to trace the change history from one to the other, including any changes that are later merged from one to the other).